# Dark Google Tango camera surface when using depth information

Tags: google-project-tango

**Situation:** I'm trying to write a Google Tango application in Java that allows the user to see the tango's camera feed with virtual objects on top (i.e. a video see-through augmented reality view) AND uses Tango depth/point cloud information.

**Problem:**  Whenever I try to enable the depth sensor on the Tango, the camera image get's very dark.  When I disable the depth sensing, everything is OK.  Here are some screen shots:

Google Tango with Depth information enabled:

```
mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
```

[image: Camera View with Depth sensing enabled]

Same application with Depth information disabled:

```
mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, false);
```

[image]

**Question:**  How do I get a clean camera image AND enable the Tango's depth information?  If pure color is not possible, can a get high contrast B/W?  I suspect this is a synchronization issue, and perhaps the surface is drawn after the depth/point cloud algorithm perturbing the image.  Or, the camera format is changed to support the depth sensing and is unsuitable for preview.

I'm using the Tango.setSurface technique suggested in this [helpful and related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771558/getting-color-data-in-java-tango-sdk-or-c-sdk?rq=1)

I'm purposefully NOT using the Android's native camera APIs.

(**EDIT**:  This post is based on Fermat update.  Have not confirmed after Gauss update)

My main activity code is posted below.  Full project is at [this github repo](https://github.com/stevehenderson/GoogleTango_AugmentedRealityTest_PointCloud)

Thanks in advance!

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.digitalblacksmith.tango_ar_pointcloud;

import com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.OnTangoUpdateListener;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoConfig;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCoordinateFramePair;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoErrorException;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoEvent;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoInvalidException;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoOutOfDateException;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoPoseData;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoXyzIjData;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * 
 * Modified Main Activity class from the Original Google Tango SDK  Motion Tracking API Sample. 
 * 
 * Creates a GLSurfaceView for the OpenGL scene, which displays a cube
 * Then adds a SurfaceView for the camera image.  The surface is connected 
 * to the Tango camera.  This is necessary if one wants to get point cloud
 * data from the Tango AND use the camera for video-see through Augmented Reality.
 * 
 * Lessons learned:  Ensure your onPause and onResume actions are handled correctly
 * in terms of disconnecting and reconnecting the Tango!!  If the Tango is not
 * disconnected and reconnected properly, you will get a black background and
 * may think the issue is something else.
 * 
 * @author  Steve Henderson @stevehenderson 
 * 
 */
public class PointCloudActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback  {

    private static final String TAG = PointCloudActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int SECS_TO_MILLISECS = 1000;


    private Tango mTango;
    private TangoConfig mConfig;
    private TextView mDeltaTextView;
    private TextView mPoseCountTextView;
    private TextView mPoseTextView;
    private TextView mQuatTextView;
    private TextView mPoseStatusTextView;
    private TextView mTangoServiceVersionTextView;
    private TextView mApplicationVersionTextView;
    private TextView mTangoEventTextView;
    private TextView mPointCountTextView;
    private TextView mAverageZTextView;
    private TextView mFrequencyTextView;
    private float mPreviousTimeStamp;
    private int mPreviousPoseStatus;
    private int count;
    private float mDeltaTime;
    private Button mMotionResetButton;
    private Button mDropBoxButton;
    //private boolean mIsAutoRecovery;

    //private PCRenderer mOpenGL2Renderer;
    private OpenGL2PointCloudRenderer mOpenGL2Renderer;
    private DemoRenderer mDemoRenderer;
    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    private SurfaceView surfaceView;

    private float mXyIjPreviousTimeStamp;
    private float mCurrentTimeStamp;

    boolean first_initialized = false;

    Surface tangoSurface;

    Vector3f lastPosition;
    Vector3f dropBoxPosition;


    /**
     * Set up the activity using OpenGL 20
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void setUpOpenGL20() {

        ///////////////////////
        //Create GLSurface
        ///////////////////////
        // OpenGL view where all of the graphics are drawn
        mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLView.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);
        SurfaceHolder glSurfaceHolder = mGLView.getHolder();
        glSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        ////////////////////////////////////
        // Instantiate the Tango service
        ///////////////////////////////////
        mTango = new Tango(this);
        // Create a new Tango Configuration and enable the MotionTrackingActivity API
        mConfig = new TangoConfig();
        mConfig = mTango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_CURRENT);
        mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_MOTIONTRACKING, true);
        ///  --->If the next property is false (disabled depth) then image ok <-------
        mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);


        // Configure OpenGL renderer
        //mRenderer = new GLClearRenderer();
        int maxDepthPoints = mConfig.getInt("max_point_cloud_elements");

        mOpenGL2Renderer = new OpenGL2PointCloudRenderer(maxDepthPoints);

        mDemoRenderer = mOpenGL2Renderer;
        mOpenGL2Renderer.setFirstPersonView();
        mGLView.setRenderer(mOpenGL2Renderer);
        mGLView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        //setContentView(mGLView);


        try {
            setTangoListeners();
        } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.TangoError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.motiontrackingpermission,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //////////////////////////
        // Create Camera Surface
        //////////////////////////
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        SurfaceHolder activitySurfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        activitySurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);


        //mGLView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        setContentView(mGLView);
        addContentView( surfaceView, new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );

        /////////////////////////
        //Create UI Objects 
        ////////////////////////
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View tmpView;
        tmpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_motion_tracking, null);
        getWindow().addContentView(tmpView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 


        mApplicationVersionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appversion);

        mApplicationVersionTextView.setText("OpenGL 2.0");

        // Button to reset motion tracking
        mMotionResetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetmotion);
        // Set up button click listeners
        mMotionResetButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Button to drop position box (breadcrumb cube)
        mDropBoxButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dropbox);
        // Set up button click listeners
        mDropBoxButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //mOpenGL2Renderer.setFirstPersonView();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setUpOpenGL20();

        // Text views for displaying translation and rotation data
        mPoseTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pose);
        mQuatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quat);
        mPoseCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.posecount);
        mDeltaTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deltatime);
        mTangoEventTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tangoevent);
        mPointCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointCount);
        mAverageZTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.averageZ);
        mFrequencyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.frameDelta);

        // Text views for the status of the pose data and Tango library versions
        mPoseStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        mTangoServiceVersionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.version);

        // Display the library version for debug purposes
        mTangoServiceVersionTextView.setText(mConfig.getString("tango_service_library_version"));

        dropBoxPosition = new Vector3f();
        lastPosition = new Vector3f();
    }

    private void motionReset() {

        mTango.resetMotionTracking();
    }

    private void dropBox() {
        dropBoxPosition.setTo(lastPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "OnPause");
        try {
            mTango.disconnect();
            Log.i(TAG,"Pausing..TANGO disconnected");
        } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.TangoError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "OnResume");

        try {
            //setTangoListeners();
        } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
        try {           
            if(first_initialized)mTango.connect(mConfig);
        } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
        try {
            //setUpExtrinsics();
        } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.resetmotion:
            motionReset();
            break;
        case R.id.dropbox:
            dropBox();
            break;
        default:
            Log.w(TAG, "Unknown button click");
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        return false; 
    }


    /**
     * Set up the TangoConfig and the listeners for the Tango service, then begin using the Motion
     * Tracking API. This is called in response to the user clicking the 'Start' Button.
     */
    private void setTangoListeners() {
        // Lock configuration and connect to Tango
        // Select coordinate frame pair
        final ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs = 
                new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();
        framePairs.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
                TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE,
                TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE));
        // Listen for new Tango data
        mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new OnTangoUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPoseAvailable(final TangoPoseData pose) {
                // Log whenever Motion Tracking enters a n invalid state
                if (pose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_INVALID) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Invalid State");
                }
                if (mPreviousPoseStatus != pose.statusCode) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                count++;
                mPreviousPoseStatus = pose.statusCode;
                mDeltaTime = (float) (pose.timestamp - mPreviousTimeStamp) * SECS_TO_MILLISECS;
                mPreviousTimeStamp = (float) pose.timestamp;
                // Update the OpenGL renderable objects with the new Tango Pose
                // data
                float[] translation = pose.getTranslationAsFloats();

                mGLView.requestRender();

                // Update the UI with TangoPose information
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        DecimalFormat threeDec = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
                        String translationString = "[" + threeDec.format(pose.translation[0])
                                + ", " + threeDec.format(pose.translation[1]) + ", "
                                + threeDec.format(pose.translation[2]) + "] ";
                        String quaternionString = "[" + threeDec.format(pose.rotation[0]) + ", "
                                + threeDec.format(pose.rotation[1]) + ", "
                                + threeDec.format(pose.rotation[2]) + ", "
                                + threeDec.format(pose.rotation[3]) + "] ";

                        float x = (float) pose.translation[0];
                        float y = (float) pose.translation[1];
                        float z = (float) pose.translation[2];

                        mDemoRenderer.setCameraPosition(x-dropBoxPosition.x, y-dropBoxPosition.y, z-dropBoxPosition.z);

                        lastPosition.setTo(x, y, z);

                        float qx = (float) pose.rotation[0];
                        float qy = (float) pose.rotation[1];
                        float qz = (float) pose.rotation[2];
                        float qw = (float) pose.rotation[3];

                        mDemoRenderer.setCameraAngles(qx, qy, qz, qw);

                        // Display pose data on screen in TextViews
                        //Log.i(TAG,translationString);
                        mPoseTextView.setText(translationString);
                        mQuatTextView.setText(quaternionString);
                        mPoseCountTextView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                        mDeltaTextView.setText(threeDec.format(mDeltaTime));
                        if (pose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_VALID) {
                            mPoseStatusTextView.setText(R.string.pose_valid);
                        } else if (pose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_INVALID) {
                            mPoseStatusTextView.setText(R.string.pose_invalid);
                        } else if (pose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_INITIALIZING) {
                            mPoseStatusTextView.setText(R.string.pose_initializing);
                        } else if (pose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_UNKNOWN) {
                            mPoseStatusTextView.setText(R.string.pose_unknown);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onXyzIjAvailable(final TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
                //Log.i(TAG,"xyzijAvailable!!!!!!!!");
                mCurrentTimeStamp = (float) xyzIj.timestamp;
                final float frameDelta = (mCurrentTimeStamp - mXyIjPreviousTimeStamp)
                        * SECS_TO_MILLISECS;
                mXyIjPreviousTimeStamp = mCurrentTimeStamp;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[xyzIj.xyzCount * 3 * 4];
                //////mGLView.requestRender();
                FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(
                        xyzIj.xyzParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                try {
                    fileStream.read(buffer,
                            xyzIj.xyzParcelFileDescriptorOffset, buffer.length);
                    fileStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    TangoPoseData pointCloudPose = mTango.getPoseAtTime(
                            mCurrentTimeStamp, framePairs.get(0));

                    mOpenGL2Renderer.getPointCloud().UpdatePoints(buffer,
                            xyzIj.xyzCount);
                    mOpenGL2Renderer.getModelMatCalculator()
                    .updatePointCloudModelMatrix(
                            pointCloudPose.getTranslationAsFloats(),
                            pointCloudPose.getRotationAsFloats());
                    mOpenGL2Renderer.getPointCloud().setModelMatrix(
                            mOpenGL2Renderer.getModelMatCalculator()
                            .getPointCloudModelMatrixCopy());
                } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.string.TangoError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (TangoInvalidException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.string.TangoError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // Must run UI changes on the UI thread. Running in the Tango
                // service thread
                // will result in an error.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    DecimalFormat threeDec = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Display number of points in the point cloud
                        mPointCountTextView.setText(Integer
                                .toString(xyzIj.xyzCount));
                        mFrequencyTextView.setText(""
                                + threeDec.format(frameDelta));
                        mAverageZTextView.setText(""
                                + threeDec.format(mOpenGL2Renderer.getPointCloud()
                                        .getAverageZ()));
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onTangoEvent(final TangoEvent event) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mTangoEventTextView.setText(event.eventKey + ": " + event.eventValue);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    private void setUpExtrinsics() {
        // Get device to imu matrix.
        TangoPoseData device2IMUPose = new TangoPoseData();
        TangoCoordinateFramePair framePair = new TangoCoordinateFramePair();
        framePair.baseFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
        framePair.targetFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
        device2IMUPose = mTango.getPoseAtTime(0.0, framePair);
        // mRenderer.getModelMatCalculator().SetDevice2IMUMatrix(
        //         device2IMUPose.getTranslationAsFloats(), device2IMUPose.getRotationAsFloats());

        // Get color camera to imu matrix.
        TangoPoseData color2IMUPose = new TangoPoseData();
        framePair.baseFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
        framePair.targetFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR;
        color2IMUPose = mTango.getPoseAtTime(0.0, framePair);

        // mRenderer.getModelMatCalculator().SetColorCamera2IMUMatrix(
        //        color2IMUPose.getTranslationAsFloats(), color2IMUPose.getRotationAsFloats());
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Surface surface = holder.getSurface();

        if (surface.isValid()) {

            mTango.connectSurface(0, surface);
            first_initialized=true;
            mTango.connect(mConfig);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mTango.disconnectSurface(0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a solution of sorts, with the help of my friends at CGUI.

In my post above, you will note that the depth camera enabled image has an underexposure error.  It seems that the Tango is doing some auto-exposure on the camera image.

When I tried it during the day time, with good natural light and some added flood lights, I received better results:

Depth enabled:

[image: with depth enabled]

Depth disabled:

[image]

So, one possible workaround/consideration when using color and depth is to carefully manage the light in the environment..This makes sense given some of the calibration routines I've seen in the Tango demo apps that call for "daylight"

**UPDATE**  You can also select the B/W fisheye camera which might be better for low-light situations if you don't mind the lack of color and distortion:

```
 mTango.connectSurface(2, surface);  //0-->color cam; 2--> B/W fisheye
```